# Are there better ways to output text with twitter API using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter

I want to stream twitter for NLP with python3, I use sublime text (IDLE is the same result), but got a lot of non 'utf-8' characters, like these:

\u0e40\u0e1b\u0e25\u0e35\u0e48\u0e22\u0e19\u0e08\u0e32\u0e01 NLP \u0e40\u0e1b\u0e47\u0e19 NPH (\u0e19\u0e31\u0e01\u0e1e\u0e39\u0e14\u0e40\u0e2b\u0e35\u0e49\u0e22) \u0e40\u0e16\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e44\u0e2d\u0e49\u0e1b\u0e4a\u0e2d\u0e1b \u0e04\u0e14\u0e35\u0e40\u0e01\u0e48\u0e32\u0e17\u0e35\u0e48\u0e44\u0e25\u0e48\u0e40\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e44\u0e1b\u0e15\u0e32\u0e22\u0e2d\u0e48\u0e30 \u0e21\u0e36\u0e07\u0e40\u0e04\u0e25\u0e35\u0e22\u0e23\u0e4c\u0e22\u0e31\u0e07\u0e2a\u0e31\u0e14 \u0e21\u0e32\u0e2a\u0e40\u0e15\u0e2d\u0e23\u0e4c\u0e04\u0e27\u0e22\u0e44\u0e23 \u0e21\u0e32\u0e2a\u0e40\u0e15\u0e2d\u0e23\u0e4c\u0e2d\u0e32\u0e23\u0e4c\u0e15\u0e2a\u0e35\u2026"

my program are:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            # print(data)



            tweet=data.split(',')[3].split('"text":')[1].split(':')[1]
            print(tweet)

            saveThis=str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
            saveFile=open('twitdb.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(tweet)
            # saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True

        except BaseException as e:
            print('failed ondata,',str(e))
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["NLP"])
```

who can help me?thanks

Comment: why don't you use encoding feature in python?

Comment: you mean to write and read file with encode "utf-8" ?

Comment: yeah, is there any problem in using utf-8?

Comment: I have saveFile, but no difference